# Error in template instantiation in GCC 4.9, works fine in GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc

The test code below works perfectly fine with GCC 4.8 (and 4.7):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, T &object, typename... Args>
struct Functor
{
    template<float (T::*function)(Args...), Args... args>
    struct Inner
    {
        float operator()() const
        {
            return (object.*function)(args...);
        }
    };
};

class Object
{
public:

    float someFunction()
    {
        return {};
    }

    float someFunctionWithArgument(int)
    {
        return {};
    }
};

Object object;

Functor<Object, object>::template Inner<&Object::someFunction> functor1;
Functor<Object, object, int>::template Inner<&Object::someFunctionWithArgument, 1> functor2;

int main()
{

}
```

However with GCC 4.9 it fails with a rather unhelpful message at the point of instantiation of `functor1`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Functor<Object, (* & object)>’:
test.cpp:33:24:   required from here
test.cpp:7:9: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
  struct Inner
         ^
test.cpp:7:9: error: provided for ‘template<class T, T& object, class ... Args> template<float (T::* function)(Args ...), Args ...args> struct Functor<T, object, Args>::Inner’
test.cpp:7:9: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
test.cpp:7:9: error: provided for ‘template<class T, T& object, class ... Args> template<float (T::* function)(Args ...), Args ...args> struct Functor<T, object, Args>::Inner’
test.cpp:33:35: error: ‘Inner’ in ‘struct Functor<Object, (* & object)>’ does not name a template type
 Functor<Object, object>::template Inner<&Object::someFunction> functor1;
```

If I comment the line with `functor1` instantiation, everything else (`functor2`) works fine.

Any ideas how to solve that?

EDIT:

I reported a bug in GCC - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64514 we'll see...

Comment: As a random stab, specialize `Functor` for empty `Args...`?  See if problem goes away?

Comment: Why do you have `template` in the declarations of functor1 and functor2?

Comment: @MarcGlisse - most likely because compiler "suggests" (with an error message) adding that when I remove it...

Comment: @Yakk - it would probably solve the issue, but I hope there's a simpler solution. The code seems _correct_ (at least it worked for a long time before update to GCC 4.9), so I'm not really sure why it fails with new GCC - is it me or the compiler?

Comment: @FreddieChopin No it doesn't...

Comment: @Marc good point, that isn't a dependent `template`, it being a `template` is clear at the point `::Inner` is mentioned.  Fred, replace `:: template Inner` with `::Inner` in the declaration of `functor1` and `functor2`?

Comment: Fwiw clang 3.5 chews this up no-problem as well.

Comment: Note that intel 14 rejects the code (for a strange reason) and solaris studio 12.4 crashes, not an easy testcase ;-)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Preview accepts the code. I don't exactly know what that tells us, but here it is!

Comment: @MarcGlisse - OK, in this example `template` keyword is indeed useless - it was a leftover from the actual code which is a bit more complex. Anyway - removing that changes nothing, the error message is identical.

Comment: Thanks for sending the bug report :-)

Answer (score 3):

I am not a hundert percent sure about whether GCC is entirely wrong. However, the problem case can essentially be reduced to

```
template<typename... T>
struct Functor
{
    template <T...>
    struct Inner
    {};
};

template struct Functor<>::Inner<>;
```

Which shows the same behavior with GCC. This code seems to be well-formed - even though `Inner` doesn't have any template arguments:

> When `N` is zero, the instantiation of the expansion produces an empty
>   list. Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic
>   interpretation of the enclosing construct, **even in cases where
>   omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed** or would
>   result in an ambiguity in the grammar.

But if we now change the code to use an alias template instead, it suddenly works:

```
template <typename... T>
struct Functor
{
    template <T...>
    using Inner = void;
};

using type = Functor<>::Inner<>;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb26c5b59b36f54). While trying to apply this solution to your problem, not only did I encounter the original bug but also a second one:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Functor
{
    template <Args... args>
    struct A;

    template <Args... args>
    using B = A<args...>;
};

using type = Functor<>::B<>;
```

> main.cpp:8:24: error: expansion pattern 'args' contains no argument
>   packs
>
> ```
>  using B = A<args...>
>                     ^
> ```

I think that GCC has a fundamental problem with "empty" non-type template parameters.